# Finding difference between two times in R

Tags: r

Trying to find time spent in bed.

```
# (Time going to bed) Start Time = PSQI_Q1
# (Time wake up) End Time = PSQI_Q3

PSQI.1 <- PSQI.1 %>% 
  mutate(Q1_times = times( sprintf( "%d:%02f:00", PSQI.1$PSQI_Q1 %/% 100, PSQI.1$PSQI_Q1 %% 100 ) )) %>% 
  mutate(Q3_times = times( sprintf( "%d:%04f:00", PSQI.1$PSQI_Q3 %/% 100, PSQI.1$PSQI_Q3  %% 100 ) )) %>% 
  mutate(TIB = Q1_times - Q3_times)
```

Here we convert integer times (600) into 24 hour "times" (06:00).
then trying to find time in bed = TIB with Q1-Q3.

This obviously only works when Q3 < Q1

tried using difftime() but get the error;

```
Error in as.POSIXct.default(time1, tz = tz) : 
  do not know how to convert 'time1' to class “POSIXct”
```

Have tried to convert class to POSIXct with no luck.

Original data doesn't have YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS, It only has HH:MM:SS. Tried to add todays date to variables to therefore get that format but still getting -16, -17 ect time differences

Some sample data but printing as days not hours:

```
structure(list(Q1_times = structure(c(0.979166666666667, 0.979166666666667, 0.989583333333333, 0.989583333333333, 0.999305555555556, 0.999305555555556), 
format = "h:m:s", class = "times"), Q3_times = structure(c(0.354166666666667, 0.375, 0.291666666666667, 0.291666666666667, 0.25, 0.3125), 
format = "h:m:s", class = "times")), 
row.names = 375:380, class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can all be done with base R functions. Both the important step of *parsing* to `POSIXct` and then the calculations for different units.

##### Code

```
startTxt <- "2023-11-22 22:23:24"   # some time last eve
endTxt <- "2023-11-23 07:08:09"     # some time this morning

## parse
startT <- as.POSIXct(startTxt)
endT <- as.POSIXct(endTxt)

## difftime
difftime(endT, startT)
## difftime in hours (explicitly selected)
difftime(endT, startT, unit="hour")
## difftime in min
difftime(endT, startT, unit="min")
## difftime in sec
difftime(endT, startT, unit="sec")

sprintf("Numerically %f %f %f\n",
        as.numeric(difftime(endT, startT, unit="hour")),
        as.numeric(difftime(endT, startT, unit="min")),
        as.numeric(difftime(endT, startT, unit="sec")))
```

##### Output

```
> startTxt <- "2023-11-22 22:23:24"   # some time last eve
> endTxt <- "2023-11-23 07:08:09"     # some time this morning
> ## parse
> startT <- as.POSIXct(startTxt)
> endT <- as.POSIXct(endTxt)
> 
> 
> ## difftime
> difftime(endT, startT)
Time difference of 8.74583 hours
> ## difftime in hours (explicitly selected)
> difftime(endT, startT, unit="hour")
Time difference of 8.74583 hours
> ## difftime in min
> difftime(endT, startT, unit="min")
Time difference of 524.75 mins
> ## difftime in sec
> difftime(endT, startT, unit="sec")
Time difference of 31485 secs
> 
> 
> sprintf("Numerically %f %f %f\n",
+ as.numeric(difftime(endT, startT, unit="hour")),
+ as.numeric(difftime(endT, startT, unit="min")),
+ as.numeric(difftime(endT, startT, unit="sec")))
[1] "Numerically 8.745833 524.750000 31485.000000\n"
>
```

If you trouble parsing input data into POSIXct, the [anytime](https://eddelbuettel.github.io/anytime) package can help without requiring format strings for many common input formats.

Comment: Forgot to say but original data doesn't have YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS, It only has HH:MM:SS.

Tried to add todays date to variables to therefore get that format but still getting -16, -17 ect time differences

Comment: `Q1_times
<S3: times>
Q3_times
<S3: times>
23:00:00 09:40:00   
23:00:00 10:00:00   
23:00:00 11:00:00   
23:00:00 11:00:00   
23:15:00 07:20:00   
23:30:00 05:30:00   
23:30:00 05:45:00   
23:30:00 06:30:00   
23:30:00 06:45:00   
23:30:00 06:45:00 `

Example of our data

Comment: Please edit the question with clarifying info / data. Rather than showing the printout, it would be best to share code that creates some of the data, eg by running `dput(head(PSQI.1))` and pasting in the output. That makes a code "recipe" that others can run to have an example with the same formatting as your data.

Answer (score 0):

```
PSQI.1$dif = (Q3_times - Q1_times) %% 1
PSQI.1$dif_hrs = PSQI.1$dif_hrs = dif * 24)
```

Result

```
     Q1_times  Q3_times       dif  dif_hrs
375 0.9791667 0.3541667 0.3750000 9.000000
376 0.9791667 0.3750000 0.3958333 9.500000
377 0.9895833 0.2916667 0.3020833 7.250000
378 0.9895833 0.2916667 0.3020833 7.250000
379 0.9993056 0.2500000 0.2506944 6.016667
380 0.9993056 0.3125000 0.3131944 7.516667
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure this out with a friend!

Thanks very much for your help! @DirkEddelbuettel and @JonSpring

Might be more complicated than it needs to be but This is what we decided on;

```
    PSQI.1 <- PSQI.1 %>% 
  mutate(Q1_times = times( sprintf( "%d:%02f:00", PSQI.1$PSQI_Q1 %/% 100, PSQI.1$PSQI_Q1 %% 100 ) )) %>% 
  mutate(Q3_times = times( sprintf( "%d:%04f:00", PSQI.1$PSQI_Q3 %/% 100, PSQI.1$PSQI_Q3  %% 100 ) ))
 
 
PSQI.1 <- PSQI.1 %>%
  mutate(dtQ1 = as.POSIXct(paste(Sys.Date(), Q1_times), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), 
         dtQ3 = as.POSIXct(paste(Sys.Date(), Q3_times), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
 
 
# Handling negative differences
PSQI.1 <- PSQI.1 %>%
  mutate(dtQ3_adjusted = ifelse(dtQ3 > dtQ1, dtQ3, 
                                          dtQ3 + dhours(24)),
         TIB = difftime(dtQ3_adjusted, dtQ1)) 

(dtQ1 and dtQ3 = date-time Q1/3)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**